# Python Django nginx uWsgi getting failed on specific callback endpoints

Tags: python, django, docker, uwsgi, django-allauth

I'm running Django web app on a docker container where I use Nginx with uwsgi.
Overall the web works just fine it fails only on specific callback endpoints during the social app (Google, Facebook) registration.

Below is the command I use to run the uswgi

```
uwsgi --socket :8080 --master --strict --enable-threads --vacuum --single-interpreter --need-app --die-on-term --module config.wsgi
```

Below is the endpoint where it fails (Django allauth lib)

```
accounts/google/login/callback/?state=..........
```

Below is the error message:

```
!! uWSGI process 27 got Segmentation Fault !!!
...
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ...
...
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 27) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 28)
```

Just FYI.. this works without any issues in the local docker container but it fails when I use the GCP container. Also, this used to work fine on GCP as well so probably something happened after recent dependency updates.

```
Environment:
Python: 3.9.16
Django: 3.2.3
allauth: 0.44.0 (Django authentication library)
Nginx: nginx/1.23.3
uWSGI: 2.0.20
```